# Heroku refuses to load my django css files

Tags: python, css, django, heroku, static

My site loads without CSS being applied. When I open DevTools, it says the browser cannot load `style.css` or any of the other images and files. I am just trying to upload a simple project, with a couple of images, and some CSS. This is the first time I have had this problem with Heroku.

Comment: Try sending the Heroku support team an email *before* posting here, since this is likely an issue related to their platform. We also can't tell much without your code, you Heroku project configuration and your directory structure.

Comment: Have you setup whitenoise? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Answer (score 0):

1- Install Whitenoise With "pip install whitenoise"

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
    # Add to this list all the locations containing your static files 
)
```